# Mongo Node query within 1 hour of timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My query to find all objects within 1 hour ago of current time (based on timestamps) is not returning data:

The schema:

```
var visitSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  userID: String,
  userName: String,
  worldID: String
});
```

Node + Mongoose back-end:

```
var d = new Date() - 60 * 60 * 1000; //1 hour ago (from now)
   
var qw = {
    timestamp: { 
        $gt: d
    },
    worldID: req.query.worldID
}    
db.collection('visits').find(qw).sort({_id: -1}).toArray(fn(req, res));
```

Comment: Check the database hour. Sometimes the hour of your db is one hour behind... I've had that issue. Also you can look at individual docs. Just add one in the mongo console and the retrive it without filters, look at the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var d = new Date() - 60 * 60 * 1000;` is returning a number (unix timestamp), not an actual Date.

Given your schema, it looks like you're storing actual Dates int the database, so you'll need to do your timestamp math, and then convert back into a Date:

`var d = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 60 * 1000);`

Comment: I prefer to just keep the timestamp as a UNIX timestamp integer rather than a date, so that it's easier to deal with and this kind of issue doesn't arise.